# js-cookie set function is returning undefined

Tags: js-cookie

Here is my index.js code (I got rid of a lot of irrelevant code):

```
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');
var Cookies = require('js-cookie');

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
if (!(Cookies.get('user_id'))) {
    cookie_id = uuidv4();
    chats_db.post({'user_id': cookie_id})
    set_cookie = Cookies.set('user_id', cookie_id, { expires: 7 }); //console.log(set_cookie) is undefined
}
else {
    console.log('returning user');
    cookie_id = Cookies.get('user_id');
    var chats = chats_db.find({
    selector: {'user_id': cookie_id},
    fields: ['_id']
}
});
```

Additionally, I installed js-cookie using "npm install js-cookie" in the root directory of my project. index.js and index.html are located in the root directory of my project.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was not using the library incorrectly. It still returns undefined, but when I use it in the console, everything works.